# How to stop match until BEFORE a character in regex

Tags: regex

```
href="assisteradmin/viewassisterinformation?assisterId=5WJwXk0P1SKR9tlgHs5XuQ">
```

I am using regexp `(assisterId=(.*?"))` which gives output as

```
 assisterId=5WJwXk0P1SKR9tlgHs5XuQ"
```

How would I get the matches until `"` but excluding `'"'` .. i.e until match before '"' character?

The  `5WJwXk0P1SKR9tlgHs5XuQ` values keeps changing.. so cannot check for `'Q'` but need something to check until before ``" excluding `"` in the result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use negated char class.

```
assisterId=([^"]*)
```

`[^"]*` matches any character but not of double quotes or not.

**OR**

use a lookahead assertion.

```
assisterId=(.*?)(?=")
```

Lookarounds won't consume any character. The above lookahead asserts that the match must be followed by a double quote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
(assisterId=([^"]*))
```

Explanation:

- `[^"]*` (negated character class) match everything which is not `"`.. so it will stop once it encounters `"`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vA6mZ3/1)